# Finding the most frequent value in SQL column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written the following code :

```
select ap.doctorsnum,doc.specialty
from appointments as ap
join doctor as doc
on ap.doctorsnum = doc.doctorsnum
```

This a screenshot of the first 10 rows of the result. (The actual result contains more than 5k rows)

[image]

How can I calculate which is the most frequent value to appear in the "specialty" column?

(All security numbers are fake, they have been randomly generated)

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What exactly is the result you want? An additional column that repeats the most frequent value? A single row and column with that value?

Comment: I would prefer a single row and column with that value.

Comment: Well, that would be daniel's answer (if you remove the `count(*)` column)

Answer (score 2):

I would make a query like:

```
SELECT 
    speciality,
    COUNT(*) AS value_occurrence
FROM appointments 
GROUP BY 
    speciality
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yeah but how would that work with my code? Your code is correct assuming that you're calculating the most frequent value in a different table. I'm trying to implement that with the code that I've written.

Comment: But your query doesn't give you the answer you want. How do you expect someone to get a different answer without changing the query?

Comment: I don't mind if you change my query. The thing is that, I'm writing code for an assignment for my uni. They've given us a dataset and I'm trying to calculate which department has had the most appoinments. As you can see I've managed to join  two columns together and I just need to find out which "specialty" appears most frequently. Daniel's code works fine for a seperate table. But I wanna make this work for the 2 columns which I've joined together.

Comment: So add the `group by`, `order by` and `limit` clauses to your query.  Once the JOIN phase is complete, **all the columns** from the  tables are available, it does not matter that there is 1 table or several.